# How leveled the wall need to be to put stick tiles on it?

Tags: drywall, walls, tile, painting

I have a wall that is almost leveled, but there are some problems:

1. Part of the old paint peeled off, so I removed the part that was peeling off. The rest still pretty good, so I didn't touch it.
2. Part of the wall has some spackling paste on it and can't be sanded much. It's almost same level, but there are some "noise".

We were thinking about putting stick tiles to make it pretty without having to worry about those problems. What are your thoughts around it? Is there anything I could paint the wall with to make is leveled?

Just a background here:
It's my very first time doing a half bathroom renovation and I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: Are the "stick tiles" you are thinking of using rated for use on a wall?  The adhesives used on floor tiles and wall tiles are different and might not be interchangeable (tiles could fall off).

Comment: Yes. I mean, we didn't even chose the stick tiles yet, but they would be specific for wals.